# ¿Como puedo exportar una sola columna del Jtable a PDF?(Java NetBeans)

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Buen día. 
Estoy tratando de exportar de un Jtable una sola columna a un PDF. El tema es que señalizo la columna que quiero exportar, pero al exportarla no se aprecia en el PDF, este esta en blanco con el titulo de Ticket nomas! Dejo mi código para ver si me echan una mano, y la librería que use es itext 4.2.2.

```
 //Creamos tabla
        PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(tbve.getColumnCount());//Creamos tabla y le pasamos numero de columnas
        //Creamos para llenar nombres columnas
        PdfPCell cabecera;
        int cantCabeceras = 0;
        int cantFilas = 0;

        cantFilas = tbve.getRowCount();
        //Rellenamos las cabeceras de las columnas de la tabla
        cabecera = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(tbve.getColumnName(1)));//Obtengo las cabeceras

        cabecera.setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);//posiciono cabeceras horizontalmente y centradas
        tabla.addCell(cabecera);//agrego cabeceras

        //Creamos para llenar las filas
        tabla.setHeaderRows(1);
        for (int row = 0; row < cantFilas; row++) {
                          tabla.addCell(tbve.getValueAt(row, 1).toString());

        }
        table.add(tabla);
        table.add(image);
        document.add(chapter);
```

Comment: Yo hubiera exportado directamente desde swing, sinceramente se me hace más fácil, a menos que necesites personalizar el estilo de la tabla en tu reporte

Comment: Si necesito personalizarla y agregar un icono también ! Esa es la prueba de un campo pero son 3 y he creado un array con las 3 cabeceras pero no hay forma de que me las muestre. Me las muestra haciendo el for para todas pero para las seleccionadas no ! :(

Comment: No estaría comprendiendo tu pregunta. El que dice de personalizalas. Y Ruslan si, necesito personalizar mi pdf ya que quito celdas y cosas que exportadas completas del swing estan y no quiero que esten !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucione al problema. Para aquel que lo tenga el error estaba en que aca `PdfPTable tabla = new PdfPTable(tbve.getColumnCount());` traía el numero completo de columnas a la tabla lo cual me instanciaba la totalidad de columnas en la tabla. Entonces lo cambie por la cantidad de columnas que voy a pasar y me la mostró en el pdf. Saludos y espero que si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema le sirva esta duda !